# Remove trailing slash on nginx except for certaing URLs

Tags: linux, nginx, regex

I'm removing the trailing slash in a nginx virtual host using the following code but I would like to prevent that from happening when the url has certaing words or slusg like i.e /bar/ or /foo/ etc.

```
if (!-d $request_filename) {
rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}
```

Could someone help me to modify the previous condition to accomplish what I exposed?

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to use a `map`. In `http` level, define the `map`:

```
map $uri $remove_slash {
    ~/bar/ 1;
    ~/foo/ 1;
    default 0;
}
```

And in `server` level, use the mapped variable:

```
if ($remove_slash) {
    rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}
```